# How can I remove dark area in a render?

Tags: rendering

When rendering (blender render, version 2.76) a fire animation, it leaves a dark field/area in the rendered picture. The size of the field seems to depend on the size of the domain around the animation.

Does anyone know how to remove this, as it kind of spoils the final result?

[image]

The blend.file can be downloaded via below link:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/1kgzxbti2b7y0g1/World+ANI22.blend

Comment: could you delete all the elements we do not need and posted a simplified .blend file to reproduce the problem so someone may point you at the right direction. On the back of my mind it could be caused by various issues.

Comment: What do you mean by deleting all elements? I will upload a blend file right away...

Comment: Well sometimes the file is too big to attach or the person asking the question don't necessary want to share the whole file. So it's ok to just delete away all stuff you don't need and only leave those stuff that are causing the described issue. Sort of cutting down the file size and focus on the problem.

Comment: Could you please add a better screenshot of the undesirable artifact?

Comment: I tried opening the file, but to no avail. The info panel says: File format is not supported in file 'C:\World+ANI22.blend'. So the only other suggestions from me are to: 1. Try setting motion blur to see if you can get rid of the hard edge of the domain. 2. Try compositing the two animations together using Render Layers, that way you can try blurring / color matching in the compositor nodes. 3. Try modifiying your smoke material to be completely alpha (just a guess).

Comment: @RickRiggs, Thanks for trying! Sorry that you are not able to load the blend file. That would have been perfect. I just tried downloaded it myself and open it on another computer - It opened up fine here, so I am not sure what to do. Perhaps remove some of the unnecessary elements as suggested by hawkenfox?
Anyway, I really appreciate you suggestions! I am quite new to this, so I am not sure how to do suggestion 2 and 3, but I will give it a try....

Comment: I have a couple more questions/comments: In this particular screenshot I see that the flame is no longer visible. If the fire has gone out at this point, couldn't you just move it out of view, so that it is no longer showing up? IF NOT - The other comment is to maybe shorten the lifetime of the smoke in the particle system, to see if it will die faster and not accumulate as much within the domain.

Comment: @RickRiggs, Again thanks for helping out! I tried suggestion 1 and 2, didn´t work. Don´t know how to do no. 3.

I have uploaded the wrong screenshot, the right one is there now. 
But you are right, as a alternative solution I could change the camera angle, so the dark area perhaps no longer is shown.

Anyway, I have come a bit further. I found out that the dark area moves when I change the position of the lamp. So it seems as if the smoke domain is casting a shadow? But I can´t find where to turn of this off? Any ideas? I know it´s really hard to help when you don´t have the blend file.

Comment: OK, posting an image in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can uncheck "Receive" in the Shadow Section for the material of the earth.

Alternatively for the fire, you could uncheck the 'Cast' checkbox.
Whatever works for your situation.

Comment: That helped! I removed cast for the smoke domain and receive for the two spheres. Not dark areas anymore. Perfect. Thanks a lot for your help!